# Pylint doesn't recognize my Python imports on VS Code, but the code runs without any error

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, anaconda, pylint

I'm working on Windows 7 64bits with Anaconda 3. On my environment Nifti, I have installed Tensorflow 2.1.0, Keras 2.3.1 and Python 3.7.7.

On Visual Studio Code there is a problem with all of these imports:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Conv2D, Conv2DTranspose, UpSampling2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, ZeroPadding2D
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
```

I get these errors:

```
No name 'python' in module 'tensorflow'
Unable to import 'tensorflow.python.keras.models'
Unable to import 'tensorflow.keras.layers'
Unable to import 'tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image'
Unable to import 'tensorflow.keras.optimizers'
```

Visual Studio Code is using the same anaconda environment: `D:\Users\VansFannel\Programs\anaconda3\envs\nifti`. I have checked it on "Python: Select Interpreter command" option in Visual Studio.

If I do this on a CMD shell with nifti environment activate, `python -c 'from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Model`, I don't get any error.

If I do with **iPython**:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Model
```

I don't get any error either.

I have checked `python.pythonpath` settings, and it points to: `D:\Users\VansFannel\Programs\anaconda3\envs\nifti`

And in the bottom left corner I can see:

[image]

When I open a new Terminal on Visual Studio Code, I get these messages:

> ```
> Microsoft Windows [Versión 6.1.7601]
> Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Reservados todos los derechos.
>
> D:\Sources\Repos\University\TFM\PruebasPython\Nifty>D:/Usuarios/VansFannel/Programs/anaconda3/Scripts/activate
>
> (base) D:\Sources\Repos\University\TFM\PruebasPython\Nifty>conda activate nifti
>
> (nifti) D:\Sources\Repos\University\TFM\PruebasPython\Nifty>
> ```

If I run the code in Visual Studio Code with `Ctrl. + F5`, **it runs** without any errors although it displays the errors on the `Problems` tab.

With pyCharm, I don't get any errors.

How an I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had tried your code, and my suggestion is to switch from pylint to other lintings. Keep away from that stupid linting. Maybe you can take a try of flake8:
"python.linting.pylintEnabled": false,
"python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,

This problem occurs because the pylint can't search the path of Anaconda, as 'tensorflow' only can be installed through conda, you only can choose the environment which created by Anaconda. But pylint can't follow the change of the environment to change the search path, so it will prompt import error. Stupid linting.

Answer (score 0):

**If you're using Anaconda Virtual Environment**

1. Close all **Open Terminals** in VS Code
2. Open a new terminal
3. Write the path to your activate folder of Anaconda in Terminal

   > Example: `E:/Softwares/AnacondaFolder/Scripts/activate`

This should now show **(base)** written at the start of your folder path

4. Now, conda activate

   > Example: `conda activate Nifti`

This should now show **(Nifti)** written at the start of your folder path

Now, if your import something, VS Code will recognize it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work. I have updated my question with more information and with what I get when I open a new Terminal on VS Code.

Comment: You can try to disable Pylint:
Go to File >> Preferences >> Settings

Search
**python.linting.pylintEnable** and set it to **false**

& Now restart VS Code

Comment: If I disable Pylint the errors disappear. But this is a very drastic way of solving the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @VansFannel The issue is with Pylint, so you either disable the specific import warning on each line, disable the specific warning globally via Pylint settings, or disable Pylint itself.